# Render dataframe column values as html in renderUI R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a variable number of values in a dataframe column that I want to render as html as part of my renderUI, how can I do this?

So if my column contained only one line, I would only want to render "line 1", but if it had two or more, I'd want it to render all of them.

Here's some example code. I tried using a loop but it did not work.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(x = c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3"))

ui <- fluidPage(

    uiOutput("lines")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$lines <- renderUI({
    div(
      h2("Lines: "),
      dat$x
    )
  })
    
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass the elements of your dataframe column as a list. To this end you could use `lapply` to loop over your vector. Note that I wrapped each element inside a `p` tag so that the lines are plotted on separate lines:

```r
library(shiny)

dat <- data.frame(x = c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("lines")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$lines <- renderUI({
      div(
        h2("Lines: "),
        lapply(dat$x, function(x) p(x))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3165
```

[image]